# How do run executable c++ through terminal in debug mode?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

I have a c++ executable file named test .. To execute it in my terminal I run.....

```
./test
```

Although I want to run it in debug mode wherein it shows the exact command being used immediately after being executed

If you are wondering what exactly I mean by debug mode..
Just like how we use -x for shell scripts

```
sh -x test.sh 
      OR
bash -x test.sh
```

This shows every command immediately after its executed .

I want same thing for this **test** c++ executable file.
I hope there would be some way.

Comment: You need to use a debugger for that.

Comment: @Mat Can you please tell the name or website of any good ones.  I will check it out

Comment: How do you even _execute a cpp file_? You need to compile it to a program, thereby tell the compile to include debug information and then run the program with an attached debugger like gdb.

Comment: @churill Well its named .cpp so i assumed its cpp. Sorry i don't have any knowledge of c++.   But since i was able to execute it.    I would like to know how do i debug it

Comment: Don't name a executable that ways, it's just confusing. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @churill unfortunately its not compiled by me. I just wanted to know the debugging info to exactly check what that executable does ( to be on the safer side ,so that it doesn't do anything dangerous )

Comment: You can't debug a program for which you don't possess the source code. If you want to inspect the machine code of the executable you have to use a decompiler aka reverse compiler. Debugger is not intended for that.

Comment: @bloody Ah i see.  Hex rays is the one people are recommending to use.  I will try.   Thanks for the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug a c++ program you need to:

## 1. Compile the program with debug information.

You need to tell the compiler to include information about symbols in the executable to be able to debug it later (at least to debug it in an easy way). For example if you use g++, add the -g option)

## 2. Run the program with attached debugger

Since your question is tagged with linux, you may want to use gdb. There also exist tools that provide a gui.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Although the c++ executable is not compiled by me.   Is there any way out ?

Comment: You can still try to run it with gdb and step through the code. There should be plenty of tutorials how to do this. Essentially it boils down to `gdb name_of_your_program` and then type s to step through the code.

Comment: Try: gdb -p pid

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute C++ source files. You have to first *compile* them into executables. Then you run the executable. C++ is *not* an interpreted scripting language.

Comment: you have to be sure that this code was compiled using `-g` flag if `g++` was used.
[This](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) could help